# SQL Group By using SQLSelect

Tags: databaselink, sql

I would like to use the `SQLSelect[]` function in Mathematica 11 to get aggregated data from a large database. Is using `SQLExecute` the only way to specify `GROUP BY`? I'd like to use some of the nice `SQLMemberQ[]` filters to use previously calculated data from Mathematica in my queries, which is a pain when using `SQLExecute`.

The way it is now, I am using StringRiffle to convert my list of filter items to something that can be used in an SQLExecute:

```
filters = {"some","words","here"};
SQLExecute[conn,"SELECT col1, SUM(col2) 
                 FROM tablename
                 WHERE col1 IN ('" <> StringRiffle[filters, "','"] <> "') 
                 GROUP BY col1"
          ]
```

I'd like to be able to use something like:

```
SQLSelect[conn,"tablename",{"col1","SUM(col2)"}, 
          SQLMemberQ[filters, SQLColumn["col1"]], 
          SQLGroupBy->SQLColumn["col1"]
         ]
```

Is there a way to specify this?

Comment: Did you make a request to WRI for this feature?